# Transition issue with BlackBerry OS 10 browser

Tags: css, mobile, blackberry, css-transitions, blackberry-10

I have the following markup (and JS code):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Visibility test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<p id="vistest">This line should fade-in after 3 seconds</p>
<script>
setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('vistest').className = 'active';
}, 3000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and main.css:

```
#vistest {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#vistest.active {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

You can [view the example online](http://stackexchange.marcelkorpel.nl/vistest/) (alas, JSFiddle doesn't work in the BB OS 10 browser, so you can't play with it).

In any browser I tried, this faded in the line of text after 3 seconds. However, on my BlackBerry phone (a Q10 with OS 10.3.1.1779) the text doesn't appear. On a test site, where this method should pop up a menu, other element styles like `:hover` and `background-color` were also not applied after changing the `class` of the to-be-faded-in element to `active`.

I tried to use the built-in web inspector of my phone, where it seems that disabling the `transition` style makes the element appear, but it doesn't disappear again when the transition rule is enabled again. Also, I managed to show the said menu when enabling desktop mode in the developer tools, but I can't reproduce this now. Also, forcing the users to manually enable desktop mode on their phones is of course a no-go.

Is this a browser bug? Can it be circumvented one way or another?

Comment: It fades in for me, but sometimes flashes at the end on Z10 10.3.1.1779. Works flowlesly on Q10 10.3.2.2134

Comment: @BojanKogoj Thanks for testing. You're sure that the Z10 doesn't have desktop mode enabled? And on both phones: can you test http://test.marcelkorpel.nl by clicking on the hamburger icon and see if the menu appears and if the titles are still shortly marked with a yellow background after clicking one of the menu items (please check it before clicking the hamburger icon to see what it looks like)? I know someone with a Z10 (don't know which OS version he uses) that got the exact same issue.

Comment: Works on both devices, scrolls, marks titles with yellow background and fades away http://i.imgur.com/CsHROoJ.png

Comment: Thanks again. For the record, this is what my screen looks like after clicking the hamburger icon: http://i.imgur.com/W2zXMR4.png no menu appears, the icon just stays selected.

Comment: Actually now that I'm trying again it won't work (on Q10). Won't open the menu, and if I use the top one it won't color title

Comment: @BojanKogoj Yes, it sometimes works for me, too, not sure if it's related to the desktop mode setting. Totally off-topic, but how did you update your OS to 10.3.2.2134? I tried to update again, but my phone says it has the most up-to-date version. Could it have something to do with my localization? I'm Dutch and using that language for my phone.